# Ranking pandas df by ordered groups

Tags: pandas, rank

Consider the following pre-ordered dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['Hat','Necklace','Bag','Bag','Necklace','Hat','Hat','Bag','Bag']})
```

I want to dense_rank the `Item` column without affecting the *current* order of the dataframe.

Namely

[image: desired output]

I have tried using

`df['bad_rank'] = df['Item'].rank(ascending=False, method='dense').astype(int)`

However, this is not what I want since 'Hat' is ranked second and should be ranked first.

I have also coded a dirty answer but I am surprised that there is not a simpler way using the rank method.

```
ordered_rank = dict(zip(df['Item'].unique(), range(1,len(df['Item'].unique())+1))) 
df['good_rank'] = df['Item'].map(ordered_rank)
```

Would someone be willing to help me out?

Comment: `df['good_rank'] = df['item'].factorize()[0] + 1`!

Comment: that works better thanks!